# Transfer value from Windows Registry into DataGridView table

Tags: c#, .net, windows, registry

I have an application which has a `DataGridView`on the main form. One of the features of the application is reading and writing to the registry from the `DataGridView`. I'm able to write to the registry and currently trying to read from the registry but having issues getting the final values into the table.

The application has three columns - Name, Age, School. The registry has a subkey named "Students" which has a few student names in it which have different values for Age and School within them. I want to get the subkey names and transfer them to the Name column in the `DataGridView`, then get the Age and School values and transfer these to the corresponding column in the table.

```
foreach (var x in Test.GetSubKeyNames())
        {
            RegistryKey product = Test.OpenSubKey(x);
            //string SubKey = Convert.ToString(product);

            Console.WriteLine("+\tKey: " + product);

            //Testing
            foreach (var value in product.GetValueNames())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("+\tValue: " + value);
                string keyValue = Convert.ToString(product.GetValue(value));

                //Having trouble here 
                StudentGridView.CurrentRow.Cells["Age"].Value = keyValue;

            }

        }

        Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Hello, you can bind the dataGridView to the registry, without writing this loops, but you must convert the subkey to an list or array, i don't know if the datagridview accepts subkeys.

Comment: Ahh I didn't realise you could do that - how do I bind it? @mehdizahrane

Comment: To make such bind, you give it a datasource , for example a have a list of students, "List<Student> list", to bind the datagridview with the list , GridView1.DataSource = list;  GridView1.DataBind();